# How can I change my Table content status

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a table.jsp file where I am getting some data from the backend. One of the field in table is status. In the status, I am getting two number like "1" and "0". But I want to show "1" means "active" "0" means "inactive". Please help me some one to solve these issue. below is my code:

/.table.jsp

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">User Online
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead style="font-size:11px;">
                            <tr>
                                <th>S.No</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Usn Number</th>
                                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                <th>Email ID</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                            
                           <c:forEach var="UserList" varStatus="status" items="${UserList}">                                         
                              <tr>
                                 <td><c:out value="${status.index+1}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.name}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.usn}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.mobile}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.email}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.Status}"/></td> <!-- currently UserList.Status = "1"/"0" is printing, if "1" show "active" if "0" show "inactive" -->
                              </tr>                       
                          </c:forEach>                                                   
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-responsive -->                   
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe jstl tag can resolve this issue, like this:

```
 <c:if test = "${userListList.status == 1}">
    active
  </c:if>
 <c:if test = "${userListList.status == 0}">
   deactivate
  </c:if>
```

and write this import sentence at the begining of the file：

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<c:when>
```

tag. For example,

```
<c:when> 
 <c:choose test="${UserList.Status == 1}">
   <td>Active</td>
</c:choose>
<c:otherwise> 
    <td> Inactive</td> 
</c:otherwise>
</c:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">User Online
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead style="font-size:11px;">
                            <tr>
                                <th>S.No</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Usn Number</th>
                                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                <th>Email ID</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                            
                           <c:forEach var="UserList" varStatus="status" items="${UserList}">                                         
                              <tr>
                                 <td><c:out value="${status.index+1}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.name}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.usn}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.mobile}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${UserList.email}"/></td>

        <c:if test = "${UserList.Status == 1}">
            <td>active</td>
        </c:if> 
        <c:if test = "${UserList.Status == 0}">
            <td>inactive</td>
        </c:if>

                              </tr>                       
                          </c:forEach>                                                   
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-responsive -->                   
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
```

I hope it will work for you.